# Spark textFileStream

Tags: spark-streaming

My spark streaming code is working perfectly when I submit it locally in my VM. It is reading files from S3 and writing output to ELK. But, when I submit the jar into EMR cluster it is giving warning saying "error reading files " and not reading at all. Is it some kind of permissions issue? I am giving all the necessary keys for my S3 bucket. Please help. Following is the stack trace.
FileInputDStream: Error finding new files java.lang.NullPointerException at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef$.length$extension(Ar‌​rayOps.scala:192) so on and so forth

Comment: Can you add the code and the full stack trace?

Comment: Thanks Marco. Following is the code

Comment: Thanks Marco. Following is the code 
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey","");
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId","");
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(30))
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val data = ssc.textFileStream("s3://xxx")
val reqdata = data.map(_.split(",")).map(t=>(t(0).toString,t(1).toString,t(2).toInt,t(3).toDouble,t(4).toInt))
reqdata.foreachRDD { edata =>           
}ssc.start()}

Comment: Following is the stack trace

Comment: Following is the stack trace WARN FileInputDStream: Error finding new files
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef$.length$extension(ArrayOps.scala:192)
 at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.length(ArrayOps.scala:192)
 at scala.collection.SeqLike$class.size(SeqLike.scala:106)
 at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.size(ArrayOps.scala:186)
 at scala.collection.mutable.Builder$class.sizeHint(Builder.scala:69)
 at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuilder.sizeHint(ArrayBuilder.scala:22)
 at

Comment: Please, add this information to the question (with code format). What I can see is that you are providing empty strings as your credentials... or you just omitted them while pasting them here? Also, add info about your hadoop and Spark version